# Select Date Between Just Day and Month Excluding Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, between

The following is the pseudo code for what I want to do:

When `Date` is `Between` `04-01` and `03-31` of the following year then output as `Q1`.

I know how to do this with the year but not excluding the year.

Comment: I think DATEPART() can help you here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: I don't know how to reconcile "of the following year" in your pseudocode with "excluding the year" in your subsequent comments.

Comment: if you dont have year in date then how can you figure out that its belongs to current year or previous year?

Comment: @Piyush because the year is in the actual record...and I need it to go from 04-01 to 03-31 of the following year....not 03-31 to 04-01...regardless off the year it will still be ending Q1 on 03-31 of the following year

Comment: @Jeff Orris :- I am not the downvoter, question does not tell what you write in comment?Your problem solved and to clarify so I can give you +1, so no affect to you

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea what you mean by output "Q1".  However, if you want your years to start on April 1st (which seems like a reasonable interpretation of what you are sking), the easiest way is to subtract a number of days.  For most years you will deal with, you can do:

```
select year(dateadd(day, - (31 + 28 + 31), date) as theyear
```

Of course, this only works three years out of four, because of leap years.  One way to fix this is with explicit logic -- but that gets messy.  Another way is to add the remaining months and subtract one year:

```
select year(dateadd(day, (30 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 31 + 30 + 31 + 30 + 31), date) - 1 as theyear
```

Comment: wouldn't one use `dateadd()` instead of `datediff()`? And mightn't it be easier to subtract 3 months rather than trying to figure out the exact number of days to subtract (which can be difficult, as you point out, due to leap years)? For that matter, one could subtract 1 quarter, e.g., `dateadd(q, -1, date)`

Comment: I meant "year ending Quarter 1".  Thank you for your answer

Comment: @DavidFaber . . . Yes, thank you for pointing that out.  (How can I make my fingers type what I'm thinking?)

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do. `Q1` usually indicates a quarter, a three-month period. A quarter running from 1 April to 31 March of the following year isn't much of a quarter :)

However, assuming you're trying to select stuff within a certain span of time starting from a particular date, you might try a little date/time arithmetic. First, a few notes:

- `datetime` values have a nominal precision of 1 millisecond (and an actual precision of approximately 3ms). That means that something like `'31 March 2014 23:59:59.999'` is rounded *up* to `'1 April 2014 00:00:00.000'`. The largest time value for a given day is `23:59:59.997'. This can have...deleterious effects on your queries if you're not cognizant of it. Don't ask me how I know this.
- `datetime` literals without a time component, such as `'1 April 2013'`, are interpreted as start-of-day (`'1 April 2014 00:00:00.000'`).

So, something like this:

```
declare
  @dtFrom datetime ,
  @dtThru datetime

set @dtFrom = '1 April 2013'
set @dtThru = dateAdd(year,1,dtFrom)

select *
from foo t
where t.someDateTimeValue >= @dtFrom
  and t.someDateTimevalue <  @dtThru
```

should probably do you.

You might want to adjust the setting of `@dtThru` to suit your requirements: if you're actually looking for the end of a quarter, you migh change it to something like

```
set @dtThru = dateAdd(month,3,dtFrom)
```

If you have a fiscal year that runs from 1 April through 31 March and want to figure out, say, what fiscal year and quarter your data represents, you might do something like this:

```
select FiscalYear    = datepart(year,t.someDateTimeValue)
                     - case datepart(month,t.someDateTimeValue) / 4
                         when 0 then 1 -- jan/feb/mar is quarter 4 of the prev FY
                         else        0 -- everything else is this FY
                       end ,
       FiscalQuarter = case datepart(month,t.someDateTimevalue) / 4
                         when 0 then 4 -- jan/feb/mar is Q4 of the prev FY
                         when 1 then 1 -- apr/may/jun is Q1 of the curr FY
                         when 2 then 2 -- jul/aug/sep is Q2 of the curr FY
                         when 3 then 3 -- oct/nov/dec is Q3 of the curr FY
                       end ,
       *
from foo t
```

Comment: I know it is a bit weird...I am tracking data for a year ending Quarter x.  Our fiscal year is a bit weird around here.  So basically it would be fiscal year ending Q1, fiscal year ending Q2, etc.  Perhaps I could have provided more clarity in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is the following:

```
SELECT year(dateadd(q, -1, mydate)) AS yearEndingQ1
  FROM mytable
```

This would give the year as `2014` for all dates between `04/01/2014` and `03/31/2015`. Of course it's possible you want a result of `2015` instead in which case you want:

```
SELECT year(dateadd(q, 3, mydate)) AS yearEndingQ1
  FROM mytable
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE per OP's comment:** "I am tracking data for a year ending Quarter x. Our fiscal year is a bit weird around here. So basically it would be fiscal year ending Q1, fiscal year ending Q2, etc. Perhaps I could have provided more clarity in my question."

This would give results in three separate columns for fiscal year ending Q1, fiscal year ending Q2, and fiscal year ending Q3. (I assume you don't need anything for fiscal year ending Q4!!)

```
SELECT year(dateadd(q, -1, mydate)) AS yearEndingQ1
     , year(dateadd(q, -2, mydate)) AS yearEndingQ2
     , year(dateadd(q, -3, mydate)) AS yearEndingQ3
  FROM mytable
```